# Kion signifas “ali”?

Tags: word-meaning

En la antaŭparolo de la libro [Sur bluaj planedoj](https://libroj.org/book/15368/s/sur-bluaj-planedoj) estas la jena frazparto:

> Kara leganto, sidiĝu kiel eble plej komforte inter la brakoj de via preferata fotelo, ĉar en la sekvaj paĝoj atendas vin klonoj, […] valizo por ali al mondofino

Mi ne trovas la vorton *ali* en vortaroj. Ĉu ĝi eble estas tajperaro? Tamen troveblas la vorto *alo* en PIV kaj ReVo, kiu signifas pli-malpli *flugilo*. Ĉu eble *ali* signifas iri per flugiloj?

En la [tekstaro](https://tekstaro.com/?s=643e7bbb8bc01) mi trovas nur unu eblan trafon. Tamen ĝi estas de la vortaro en la libro pri reformita Esperanto de Zamenhof, kaj aperas nur la vorto en listo sen klarigo. Ĉu ĝi eble estas anstataŭa propono por *iri*?

Answer (score 4):

Literatura libereco, absolute rara, unika. De la prepozo **al**, notu la *"... ali al ..."*.

Mi esperas kompreni tion.

Comment: Ho jes, tio ŝajnas bona klarigo.

Answer (score 3):

Estas surprize malfacila afero priskribi moviĝon de unu loko al alia sen esprimi manieron, kiel tio okazas. Ne ekzistas unuanimeco, ĉu ekzemple *iri, ekskursi, migri, vagi* nepre implicas, ke oni moviĝas piede aŭ nepre ne per piedoj aŭ restas malklare. Eble en la rakonto la verkisto volis lasi la manieron malfermita kaj ne uzis *iri* por eviti mentalan bildon de piediro, kial ri inventis verbon, kiun neniu alia uzis (neniom da trafoj en Tekstaro).

Comment: Ĉu _iri_ pensigas ke oni moviĝas piede? Tio surprizas min, ĉar mi kredis ke ĝi estas ĝuste la neŭtrala vorto por moviĝi de unu loko al alia sen precizigi la manieron. La unua difino en PIV ŝajne kongruas kun tio kion vi diras, ke oni moviĝas per la «tiucelaj membroj», sed la unua difino en ReVo estas pli malpreciza kaj eĉ havas ekzemplon «iri per ŝipo, veturilo» ktp. Hm, eble tio meritas apartan demandon.

Comment: Ankaŭ mi kredis, ke "iri" estas neŭtrala, kaj mi komprenas tiujn difinojn en PIV tiel, ke kelkfoje "iri" implicas moviĝon per piedoj, sed ne ĉiam (rigardu ekz. la difinon 4). Sed kelkaj ŝajnas uzi ĝin ekskluzive pri perpieda moviĝo, ekz. "ĉu vi iros aŭ veturigos?", en kiu "iri" klare estas malo de uzado de aŭto. Kp. "cŭ vi iros piede aŭ aŭte?"

Answer (score 0):

Esperanto permesas krei verbojn el substantivoj kaj adjektivoj, kaj do kial ne el adverboj?
Ĝi ne estas Literatura libereco, ĝi estas la perfekta interpreto de Esperanto,laŭ mi.